# How to link static files in django, if the path is provided by the context in html?

Tags: html, css, django, static

Here is my `views.py` file:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

def page(request):
    css = 'temp/css.css'
    return render(request, 'temp/index.html', {'css': css})
```

and `templates/temp/index.html` file:

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '{{ css|safe }}' %}">
    </head>

    <body>
        Hello Page
    </body>

</html>
```

and `static/temp/css.css` file:

```css
* {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: red;
}
```

After rendering source of the page is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/%7B%7B%20css%7Csafe%20%7D%7D">
    </head>

    <body>
        Hello Page
    </body>

</html>
```

but I am expecting

```html
...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/temp/css.css">
...
```

Why it is not working? Is there any way to do this? How to link a static file if the path is provided by the `context` in html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming 'css' is your context variable, you should be able to just do the below.  Basically drop the quotes around the 'css' variable.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static css %}">
```

Comment: Wow, It worked! Could you please provide some references?

Comment: Not sure which reference you are looking for, but here is the one for template variables [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#variables).  Context variables can be used inside tags.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/temp/css.css">` to your index.html directly. That way it will take care of itself and you don't need to pass it as the context.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know we can do that like the way you described. But I want to do the same thing by passing the path of the file or remote URL as the context. I just want to know we can do this or not, If yes then how?